# Calling multiple API requests and waiting for response using Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

**Code changes applied.**

I followed a guide on how to create a kotlin coroutine and do network request and ended up with:

```
suspend fun <T : Any> safeApiCall(call: suspend () -> Response<T>): ApiResult<T> {
    return safeApiResult(call)
}

private suspend fun <T: Any> safeApiResult(call: suspend ()-> Response<T>) : ApiResult<T>{
    val response = call.invoke()

    return if (response.isSuccessful) {
        val body = response.body()

        if (body == null) {
            ApiResult.Error(response.code())
        } else {
            ApiResult.Success(body)
        }
    } else {
        ApiResult.Error(response.code())
    }
}

suspend fun getSnappedPoints(path: String): ApiResult<SnappedPointsData> {
    return safeApiCall(
        call = { googleRoadsService.getSnappedPoints(path).await()}
    )
}
```

and calling the network request looks like this:

```
private fun getSnappedPoints() {
    val paths = Utils.getPathFromLocations(locations)

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val results = paths.map {
            async { googleRoadsRepository.getSnappedPoints(it) }
        }.awaitAll()

        Timber.i("results: ${results.size}")

        val snappedPoints = ArrayList<LocationSnap>()

        results.forEach {
            if (it is ApiResult.Success) {
                snappedPoints.addAll(it.data.snappedPoints)
            }
        }

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            if (snappedPoints.isNotEmpty()) {
                drawPolyline(snappedPoints)
            } else {
                showError()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Current problem:**

The function `getSnappedPoints()` is called when I click on specific item. For the very first time it actually calls google API and result is > 0 (size), but if I go back and click second time on the same/other item, `getSnappedPoints()` is called, `paths` is not Empty, but somehow it does not call `googleRoadsRepository.getSnappedPoints(it)` and kinda skips that step in debug and all I can see is that result is always 0. What could cause this?

Comment: What is `Repository.getPoints()`? It has a parameter while the `getPoints` shown in the question has no argument. What is result2 in this context here? which type of if condition is this?

Comment: Please formulate the question so it has only the explicitly needed information - as code as description - since I don't understand your problem. What should work? How would a test look like? Why does it not work?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC BY-SA license). Please see [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) for more information on how deleting content works on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Each coroutine (`launch`) is a unit of concurrency, if you want to run each request concurrently, you'll have to do a `launch`/`async` for each concurrent request.

```
private fun getPoints() {
    val multipleParams = Utils.getArrayListOfParams()

    coroutineJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val results = multipleParams.map {
            async { Repository.getPoints(it) }
        }.awaitAll()

        // Do something with results, once all have been gotten.
        // result and result2, result[it] has finished, continue)
    }
}
```

Bonus:

- If you create a `CoroutineScope` without cancelling it, then you should use `GlobalScope` as an optimisation. (Like so `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)`)
- You don't need `Dispatchers.IO` to do this, since it appears you are not blocking the coroutine/thread. `Dispatchers.Default` will do just fine.
- I'm not sure what you're using `coroutineJob` variable for but it looks suspicious.

Comment: Thanks for information. I actually want to block and wait all the responses so I do have to use Dispatchers.IO if Im not mistaken. Also, I edited post so maybe you can take a look. I get results for the first time when I call function, but after that awaitAll step feels like is skipping (when I use debugger) and it goes straight to result, which obviously is 0.

Comment: When you say block, are you sure you don't mean suspend?

Comment: Debugging and coroutines aren't very good friends just yet (since the call stack is transformed), so I wouldn't fully rely on it. Trying just using println statements to confirm the behaviour.

Comment: I meant suspend, yes. Noted about debugger.

Answer (score 0):

While you at IO thread so what is the necessity of using `async + await`? At the IO scope, you are free to suspend and wait for the response.

Try this one and notify me to know what will the result?

```
private fun getSnappedPoints() {
val paths = Utils.getPathFromLocations(locations)

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val results = paths.map {
        googleRoadsRepository.getSnappedPoints(it)
    }

    // rest of you code...
}
```

Comment: Zero results. What I want is to block thread and not move further till the results variable has been filled/received from API call and only then do changes on UI thread (meanwhile show loader).

Comment: @PeteWonder Which part of code not executed? is `googleRoadsService.getSnappedPoints(path).await()` part executed? Could you see the log of API call in the Logcat? or the API call is not triggered?

Comment: Looks like that. I set debug point to googleRoadsRepository.getSnappedPoints(it), but it automatically hops to next line of Timber log.

Comment: @PeteWonder It's weird, Are you sure the `paths` is not empty?